# TFS 2017 update Agent pool V 1 to V2.x

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to update the build agent (TFS 2017) from V1.x to V2.x what i tries are:

I followed these steps 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts' but the issue is my url is http not https.

1) is there any easy way to update the build agent instead above link because setting https getting connectivity/cert issues.

Do i have only PAT is the only option? any thing else apart from PAT to update the build agent. i even tries 'update all' nothing happens and no errors.

any help would be great-full. Thanks.

Comment: Why is HTTP vs HTTPS an issue? If you're not using HTTPS, then use an HTTP address. If you're using a self-signed certificate, then get a real certificate -- you shouldn't use a self-signed cert for production deployments.

Comment: If i type 'http://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool' getting URL not found. Looks like strictly i have to have https?

Comment: regarding the production deployment. we have only one server that is for test and production.

Comment: You don't need to have HTTPS configured. Is your team project collection actually named `DefaultCollection`? Can you navigate to the agent pool administration screen through the UI?

Comment: Yes from the link ->'http://{Server_Name}.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/' selected through UI and here i can able to select agents 'http://{Server_Name}.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool?poolId=1&_a=agents'

Comment: Thank you. Actually the link that is provided doesnt help much. in powershell i went /help command that gave me more details what to do. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter you are using http or https, you could both update build agents properly. If directly entire the url in the browser could not reach the right page.

You could also try to navigate to `http://yourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_projects` page and clcick the configuration button, select the **Agent Pools** in the drop down list.

[image]

---

Back to the original requirement, according to [Daniel Steiner](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/757c5dfc-2d47-496d-ad76-46d4eb87948d/update-all-agents-not-working-after-upgrading-to-tfs-2017-onprem?forum=tfsbuild) there are 2 kinds of agents:

- Windows specific agents (version 1.x)
- cross platform agents (version 2.x)

In TFS 2017 the Windows specific agents (version 1.x) are deprecated. Thus **they won't be updated from the agent queues admin area**. So you have to **download the agent** from tfs (or [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases)) and **install it yourself**. After initial installation/configuration the agent updates via tfs should work again. It would have been cool if they automated that process or at least said what to do in tfs.

Comment: So finally i convert our site with https with self signed cert.

Comment: based on this : 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases
1. Downloaded 
2. After Download:

Windows: 
C:\> mkdir myagent && cd myagent
C:\myagent> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem ; [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory("$HOME\Downloads\vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.122.1.zip", "$PWD")

3. Configure the agentDetailed instructions (These instructions from the download agent)
PS C:\agent> .\config.cmd


 


When I do the steps I get the below error

Comment: @Speed Which error? Besides did you mean you have changed your TFS url format from http to https?

Comment: Thank you. Actually the link that is provided doesnt help much. in powershell i went /help command that gave me more details what to do. Thanks again for all your help